# Web Crawling: get shares of Youtube Video from statistics tab

Tags: web-scraping, youtube, youtube-api, web-crawler, extract

Does anybody know a way to get the shares of youtube videos (not mine)? I would like to store them into a DB. It is not working with the yt api. Another problem ist that not every yt video has the statistics tab.

So far I tried the Youtube API, jsoup HTML Parser (the div showing the shares wasn't there, altough it is shown via inspect in firefox e.g) and import.io demo which was working but is definitely too expensive.

[image: Thats what I would like to extract]

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to look at the network logs, in this case it shows a `POST` on :

```
https://www.youtube.com/insight_ajax?action_get_statistics_and_data=1&v=$video_id
```

It sends a XSRF token in the body that is available in the original html body of the video page `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$video_id` in a javascript object like :

```javascript
yt.setConfig({
    'XSRF_TOKEN': "QUFFLUhqbnNvZUx4THR3eV80dHlacV9tRkRxc2NwSjlXQXxBQ3Jtc0ttd0JLWENnMjdYNE5IRWhibE9ZdDJTSk1aMktxTDR5d3JjSnkzVUtQWVcwdnp3X0tSOXEtM3hZdzVFdjNPeGpPRGtLVU5pVXV0SmtfdWJSUHNqTVg2WXBndjZpa3d6U25ja2FTelBBVWRlT0lZZkRDaDV6SU94VWE3cnpERHhWNVlUYWdyRjFqN1hvc0VLRmVwcEY3ZWdJMWgyUmc=",
    'XSRF_FIELD_NAME': "session_token",
    'XSRF_REDIRECT_TOKEN': "VlhMkn6F56dGGYcm4Rg7jCZR0vJ8MTQ5ODA1NzIwMkAxNDk3OTcwODAy"
});
```

It also needs some cookies set in this same video page.

## Using [python](/questions/tagged/python)

with [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) & [python-requests](/questions/tagged/python-requests) :

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re 

s = requests.Session() 

video_id = "CPkU0dF4JKo"

r = s.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}'.format(video_id))

xsrf_token = re.search("'XSRF_TOKEN'\s*:\s*\"(.*)\"", r.text, re.IGNORECASE).group(1)

r = s.post(
    'https://www.youtube.com/insight_ajax?action_get_statistics_and_data=1&v={}'.format(video_id), 
    data = {
        'session_token': xsrf_token
    }
)
metrics = [
    int(t.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').split(' ', 1)[0])
    for t in BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml").find('html_content').find("tr").findAll("div", {"class":"bragbar-metric"})
]
print(metrics)
```

## Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

with [curl](/questions/tagged/curl), [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) & [xml_grep](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/tools/xml_grep/xml_grep) :

The following bash script will :

- request the video page `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$video_id` with [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/)
- store the cookies in a file called `cookie.txt`
- extract the `XSRF_TOKEN` called `session_token` in the following request with [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt)
- request the video statistic page `https://www.youtube.com/insight_ajax?action_get_statistics_and_data=1&v=$video_id` with [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/) with the cookies previously stored
- parse the xml result extract the `CDATA` part with [`xml_grep`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/tools/xml_grep/xml_grep)
- parse the html with [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) to extract the `bragbar-metric` class div and convert the html result to json with `json{}`
- use [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt) to remove unicode character

The script :

```sh
video_id=CPkU0dF4JKo

session_token=$(curl -s -c cookie.txt "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$video_id" | \
    sed -rn "s/.*'XSRF_TOKEN'\s*:\s*\"(.*)\".*/\1/p")

curl -s -b cookie.txt -d "session_token=$session_token" \
    "https://www.youtube.com/insight_ajax?action_get_statistics_and_data=1&v=$video_id" | \
    xml_grep --text_only 'html_content' | \
    pup 'div table tr .bragbar-metric text{}' | \
    sed 's/\xc2\x91\|\xc2\x92\|\xc2\xa0\|\xe2\x80\x8e//' | \
    sed 's/\s.*$//'
```

It gives number of views, time watched, subscriptions, shares:

```
120862
454
18
213
```